# I deleted data in one of my apps by mistake in Firebase

Tags: firebase

firebase data:get /messages -f my-firebase-db | python -m json.tool

Using the code above in Firebase CLI, I copied data from one app to another, I didn't think it would overwrite what was already there. Is there any chance I can get that data back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a backup? If so, restore it.

Comment: If you don't have a backup and the data is important for you, reach out to firebase-support@google.com. We make daily backups of the database, so can restore it from there.